# JWT Key -> exp claim show me an exception

Tags: php, exception, jwt, token, exp

I'm doing a program who can encode and decode a token with JWT method. My encode method works fine, but when i try to decode my token with an **exp** claim my program sent me this :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException: Expired token in ..\Jwt Key\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php:134***

My code :

```
$token2 = array(
    "iss" => "example.org",
    "aud" => "http://apigateway/api/oauth/token",
    "exp" => 1340452126,
    "iat" => 1340451826
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token2, $privateKey, 'RS256');
echo "Encode:\n" . print_r($jwt, true) . "\n";

JWT::$leeway = 60; // $leeway in seconds
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $publicKey, array('RS256'));

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
echo "Decode:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "\n";
```

I use a JWT library. The error takes me to the file **JWT.php** line 134 :

```
// Check if this token has expired.
if (isset($payload->exp) && ($timestamp - static::$leeway) >= $payload->exp) {
    throw new ExpiredException('Expired token');
}
```

I search on the web and i can't find the one.. Thank you for your help !

Comment: This error is correct. If your token is expired, you don't want to continue the process. Either refresh it using a refresh token or tell the frontend it can't use this token anymore.

Comment: The error is very clear and says that the JWT token you are trying to read has expired.

Comment: the exp is 2012-06-23 13:48